# m2eclipse does not respect update policy setting

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

When updating Maven projects in Eclipse I would like Eclipse to always check for newer Snapshot dependencies in the repository and to download them.

It works for Maven from command line as I have set the **updatePolicy** to **always** in my `settings.xml`. But Eclipse does not respect this setting though I told Eclipse to use my `settings.xml`.

In Eclipse it works only if I click "Maven -> Update Project" and check the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" setting. Unfortunately this cannot be set as default.

Is this an intended behaviour or is it a bug of the **m2eclipse** plugin that the updatePolicy is not considered?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify in the pom that snapshot dependencies should be updated. For example

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>myRepo</id>
        <url>http://hostname/path/to/repos/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I prefer to specify this kind of thing directly in the pom as opposed to in `settings.xml` because in the pom it's portable, as opposed to relying on `settings.xml` being configured correctly on every machine that does builds.

Plus, in your specific scenario, the pom setting is respected in Eclipse m2e.